# Cannot find fusionchart package. GET http://localhost:4200/fusioncharts.charts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, fusioncharts

**Module1.module.ts**

```
//Adding fusion charts
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
import * as Widgets from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets";
//No error in this module
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Widgets, FusionTheme );
```

**Module2.module.ts**

```
    // Import angular-fusioncharts
    import { FusionChartsModule } from "angular-fusioncharts";
    // Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
    import * as FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
    import * as Charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
    import * as FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
    // Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
    FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

   //Error in this module.
    GET http://localhost:4200/fusioncharts.charts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Inference**.

1. I have imported FusionChart at module level for each type of chart I wanted to use.
2. Same level module imports interfere with each other.
3. On changing **Module1.module.ts to following.**

**Module1.module.ts**

```
    //Adding fusion charts
    import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
    import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
    import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
    import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
    import * as Widgets from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets";
    //Charts is added. Now 404 error in module2.module.ts is resolved
    FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Widgets, Charts , FusionTheme );
```

**Can someone explain what should be the right approach to import FusionCharts in Angular?
Whether to import all need charts in root module or import it as needed in respective modules?**

Comment: @praveen..in Module1.ts try same as Module2.ts
------import * as FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";

Comment: @MukulSharma Sorry that was typing mistake. I have edited it.

Comment: Are you still facing the problem, here is a sandbox demo you can refer - https://codesandbox.io/s/ww2y9w1m0l